# Create a GML with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, xml, gml

i would like to create a GML after finishing drawing:

```
import GML3 from 'ol/format/GML3';
this.draw_add.on('drawend',
          function (this: any, e: any) {
            this.myFeature = e.feature;
            if (this.myFeature) {
           var geometry = this.myFeature.getGeometry();
           var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

           var format = new GML3({
          featureType: 'p_bus_ndv',
          srsName: 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#3857',
          featureNS: "http://localhost:8080/SNCF",
          hasZ:true
        });

          console.log('format', format);

          

 var gml3 = format.writeGeometry(geometryy, {
              featureProjection: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857',
              dataProjection:'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857'
            })
            console.log('gml3', gml3)
           
     }}
```

in the console.log('gml3', gml3) i got :

```
<geom xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#3857"><pos srsDimension="3">34292.18836373964 6136251.654085412 0</pos></Point></geom>
```

and when i do :

```
console.log(format.getType());
```

i got that the type is : XML

And it's not what I'm looking for, I want a GML like this one;

```
 <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2154">
          <gml:coordinates  decimal="." cs="," 
                 ts="">1048042.8053806333,6845421.559760123,0</gml:coordinates>
           </gml:Point>
```